# IE9 Browser Troubleshooting Suggestions

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Website: http://tinyurl.com/2c5cxkc

This website loads fine on Safari/Chrome/Firefox. A number of people are having issues when viewing the website in IE8 and IE9.
Screenshot: http://i44.tinypic.com/29uycy1.jpg

The issue is that I can't reproduce the same on my end. I have attempted to load and reload the website multiple times in IE8 and IE9 but the website displays fine.

What would be a good way to troubleshoot this? Could you please visit the website in IE8 and IE9 and let me know if the website loads correctly or if it looks like the screenshot?

Many thanks!

Comment: IE8, win7/64:  It looks like the screenshot until I turn on "compatibility mode" after which it looks like it does in Firefox but with some javascript errors.

Comment: Hi James,
Thanks - On my computer I turned on/off compatibility mode (Win 7, IE9) and it displays correctly either way.

Would you recommend forcing the browser to use compatibility mode using a meta tag: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe I found the answer. In my style.css file I only had one line:

@import url("css/common.css");

This works fine on all browser except it causes problems in IE8/IE9. Adding all styles into the style.css files (instead of in css/common.css) fixed the problem.

I am not sure if this is an IE bug or documented feature? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No it is look fine.

maybe you friends has stopped some options in there IE [like disable flash\WMP and things like that]

Comment: Hi, the website doesn't use any flash and I've found it is not an WMP issue... Any other ideas?